# Check/eliminate different row/columns in Backtracking function javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, sudoku, backtracking

I have this code to solve a 3x3 sudoku (Only rows/columns are need to be checked, there can be 4 of the same numbers in one block, for example this is a good one:
123
231
312
)

I have the function fillsquare, with input an array [[1,2,0],[0,3,1],[3,0,2]] where the 0 need the be changed to the right number.

```
function fillsquare(square){
for (var a = 0; a<4; a++){
    for (var b = 0; b<4; b++){
        if (square[a][b] === 0){
            // do the function to check whether I can enter the right number
        }
        else {
            // ?????????????????????

        }
        }
    }
}
```

According to my professor, it should be a recursive code, but I dont think this is recursive, anyways this base will work.

I still need to change the 0's to the number that fits in place.

I have a small clue how to do this with bruteforce/backtracking, but no code to achieve this.
enter 1 in the zero, if there isn't a one in the row or column, continue to the next zero. Else enter 2 and check again etc.

I hope you can help!

PS: My prof. gave me this psuedocode for checking etc.:

```
function fillSquare(square) {
find first 0 in square
if (there is no 0) {done!}
else {determine every value that can be put on the place with the zero
(check column and row) save them for example in a temprary row
for (every possible value) {

fillSquare(square with value filled in place)
}
}
}
```

I hope this is a bit clear, it is translated;)